# How can I inject a library to my Angular 1.5 App only when I load a certain page (view, controller)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my library is quite big and I'm looking for ways to load it only when needed.

Comment: Trying searching for 'lazy loading'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mechanism named $ocLazyLoadProvider for example like here:

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    'debug': true, // For debugging 'true/false'
    'events': true, // For Event 'true/false'
    'modules': [{ // Set modules initially
        name : 'state1', // State1 module
        files: ['app/components/state1/state1Module.js']
    },{
        name : 'state2', // State2 module
        files: ['app/components/state2/state2Module.js']
    }]
});
```

Using this you can simple load these javascript libraries that you need. You can load javascript files, css files.

Comment: More information you can find here: ciphertrick.com/2016/07/06/lazy-load-modules-and-controllers-in-angularjs/